# Lookup and Relationship with multiple columns

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am completely new to Access, but I've done the tutorials, and have some VBA experience with Excel, so I shouldn't be hopeless.

I haven't progressed to forms yet, right now I'm focusing on getting the tables defined and populated, and relationships defined.

I've changed the actual tables in the example here, but the context and problem hold.

Table 1 is Food. Other than the autofield key, it has two fields

```
FoodCat  FoodType  
Fruit    banana    
Fruit    apple     
Fruit    pear     
Meat     lamb
Meat     beef
Meet     Chicken
Vegetable Broccoli
```

etc....

This table is used by another table, in a lookup and relationship setup.
It is easy to set it up so the other table has a field that is restricted to entries with the items in the FoodCat Field (although it is repetitive). I can also restrict the next field to entries with the FoodType Field, but this gives me all the choices.

What I'd like to do, in the new table, is restrict the FoodType choice to the entries that have a matching FoodCat choice.

So, if the item selected on the new table under FoodCat is Meat, I only want the FoodType choices to be lamb, beef, or chicken.

Is this even possible within the table? Do I need to use Forms to get this done?

Comment: I think a form is a better place to attempt this. Using VBA you can change the `RowSource` property of the combo box to restrict the choices. Quoting from "The Ten Commandments of Access": *"Thou shalt never allow thy users to see or edit tables directly, but only through forms"* ( http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm )

Comment: Thanks. I read these, and was very surprised by the evilness of lookup tables. All the access training enthusiastically supports them. How can I create any relation between tables without the lookup tables?

Comment: I've answered your comment below. Aside from this particular problem, I suggest you get a good book on Access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering to your comment:

When you use "Lookup" fields" you are forcing a new relation between the tables.

The best way to avoid the problems listed in the [Ten Commandments of Access](http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm) (specifically: [The evils of the lookup fields in tables](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm) ) is to create the relations manually, and then use them to create the adequate "lookup" control in a form or report.

Let's say you have the following tables:

**`tblCategories`**

```
id | catName
---+-----------
1  | Fruit
2  | Meat
3  | Vegetable
```

**`tblFood`**

```
id | idCat | foodName
---+-------+-------------
1  | 1     | Apple
2  | 1     | Banana
3  | 2     | Lamb
4  | 2     | Beef
5  | 3     | Broccoli
```

In this example is obvious that there's a one to many relation between these two tables, and that the `idCat` field in `tblFood` is a foreign key. You can create this relation by hand in the "Relations" window.

With the following query you can get both the `foodName` and `catName` fields properly (a good thing to build reports):

```
select f.*, c.catName
from tblFood as f
    inner join tblCategories as c on f.idCat = c.id;
```

This would throw something like this:

```
id | idCat | foodName | catName
---+-------+----------+------------
1  | 1     | Apple    | Fruit
2  | 1     | Banana   | Fruit
3  | 2     | Lamb     | Meat
4  | 2     | Beef     | Meat
5  | 3     | Broccoli | Vegetable
```

which is a nice and useful query that you can use in a report... without the need of using Combo Boxes in the report.

So: How on earth to build a control, for example, a `ComboBox`, that filters only the `foodName` values depending on a `catName` value?

First: Create the form

Then: Create a Combo Box and put this in the `RowSource` property:

```
select id, catName from tblCategories
```

Set the control to have two columns, and column widths: `0, 10`. This will make the `id` column in the drop-down list "invisible". Be sure to know the name of this combo box (let's say it is named `comboBox01`).

Now, create a second combo box, keep the `RowSource` property empty, and set the column widths to `0, 10`. Also be sure to know the name of this second combo box (let's say it is named `comboBox02`).

And now let's make VBA do what you need: On the properties sheet of the `comboBox01` control, look for the `afterUpdate` event, clic on the ellipsis button, select "VBA code" and write the following

```
Sub comboBox01_afterUpdate() ' This is added automatically by the VBA editor
    strSQL = "select id, foodName from tblFood where idCat=" & comboBox01.Value
    comboBox02.rowSource = strSQL
    comboBox02.Requery
End Sub ' This is added automatically by the VBA editor
```

---

"Lookup controls" (no "lookup fields") are very useful when used in forms. They can save a lot of headaches to the users of your database (you included). But **I strongly recommend you to avoid creating them directly in the tables**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do within the table.  However, it's easier to do through a form and it's more practical to do through a form.  You NEVER, EVER want your user interacting directly with a table.