# Using a form without a lookup field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to follow the commandment of not using a lookup field and getting stuck doing something that is hopefully simple.

Table People:
PrimaryID, 
EmployeeID, 
LastName, 
FirstName, 
PhoneNumber

Table Tasks: PrimaryID, EmployeeID, Summary, DueDate, Status

I've got the EmployeeID linked from People to Tasks in a 1 to Many Relationship.
Queries work fine, so I know the link is good.

Here's the problem: People don't generally know other people's ID, they know the last name. This causes a problem in populating the Tasks table.

I'd like to create a form for Tasks that has a combobox (or something similar) that gives a dropdown of Employee.LastName options, then fills in the Tasks.EmployeeID automatically. I'm getting stuck on the first step. I've got the dropdown to work, it shows me the names, but when I click one, it never updates anything. It's all blank.

Is there an easy way (preferably without VBA) to do this - or am I violating some database rule by even attempting to do such a thing?

TL;DR - I want to use a human readable field (lastname) from a source table to provide a different field value (employeeid) from the same table into a field on the destination table (tasks) - using forms, not lookup fields, because I've been told they are bad, and can't figure out the right method.

Thanks,

Grommit

EDIT: It apppears that this has been answered already as a supplement to a different question I posted before: I missed the email telling me it had been updated.
[Lookup and Relationship with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368293/lookup-and-relationship-with-multiple-columns?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

See Edit with link above, I missed a great response to a previous related question.